# Transaction Prioritization

Tags: signed-extensions, mempool

My understanding is that the Transaction-Payment Pallet prioritizes transactions based on tip, weight and length of the transaction. `ChargeTransactionPayment::get_priority` uses this data to give priority to a transaction.

**Question**:

If I want to change the priority of certain transactions.

1. Do I need to make the modification in the Transaction-Payment-Pallet?
2. Create another SignedExtension?

If I can create another Signed Extension, does it matter what order inside `SignedExtra` is in? For example, do I need to place this SignedExtension after  Transaction-Payment-Pallet SignedExtension to prevent an overwrite from Transaction-Payment-Pallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Substrate transaction queue uses the [`TaggedTransactionQueue`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_transaction_pool/runtime_api/trait.TaggedTransactionQueue.html) Runtime API to query the runtime about the validity and priority of queued transactions.

Under the hood, this is usually implemented in the runtime as

```rust
    impl tx_pool_api::runtime_api::TaggedTransactionQueue<Block> for Runtime {
        fn validate_transaction(
            source: TransactionSource,
            tx: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            block_hash: <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
        ) -> TransactionValidity {
            Executive::validate_transaction(source, tx, block_hash)
        }
    }
```

The [`TransactionValidity`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/transaction_validity/type.TransactionValidity.html) is a `Result<ValidTransaction, _>, where a` ValidTransaction` has a field

`priority: TransactionPriority // = u64`

Under the hood, `Executive::validate_transaction` uses the [`CheckedExtrinsic::validate`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/generic/struct.CheckedExtrinsic.html#method.validate) function, which in turn invokes the [`SignedExtension::validate`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html#method.validate) function.

In order to plug into this part of Substrate, you should create an alternative `SignedExtension` with a custom `validate` function that returns a suitable `TransactionValidity`.

Comment: Thanks for this insight! I am kinda surprised that an alternative UncheckedExtrinsic is preferred over implementing a SignedExtension. Do you know why we would avoid using a SignedExtension?

Comment: Actually, `SignedExtension` is possibly better. It uses the same mechanism but looks easier to plug in.

Comment: @Yatusabes the answer is correct. If you want to modify the priority, create a new SignedExtension. Order matters

Comment: So all reprioritization should be done after the transaction payment pallet? What is the impact on performance when adding a signed extension after the transaction payment pallet vs. modifying the Transaction-Payment-Pallet?

Comment: I am afraid the only way to answer you question is benchmarking: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2950/527

To be honest, I think the difference if any is going to be minimal since you'll be applying the same logic in both places. It would be more about what is the overhead of adding a new `SignedExtension`.

My recommendation is not to touch `transaction-payment` as it will be easier for your code maintenance when upgrading Substrate versions.