# Dispatch of extrinsic that has prevalidate function which emits events and modifies storage

Tags: storage, weight, transactional, unsigned

TLDR: *How to implement a substrate unsigned call, which performs storage modifications and emits events during it's validation? If transaction fails, it seems like it leaves garbage in runtime, due events/storage modifications are not reverted (see docs below).*

Let's say there is an extrinsic, which is an unsigned transaction with following body:

```rust
#[pallet::call_index(1)]
#[pallet::weight(42)]
#[frame_support::transactional]
pub fn extrinsic(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    ..
) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
    let _ = ensure_none(origin)?;

    let prevalidate_data = Self::prevalidate_something(..)?;

    Self::do_something(..);

    // Adjust weight to performed computations
    let weight = Self::calc_weight(&prevalidate_data);

    Ok(PostDispatchInfo {
        actual_weight: Some(weight),
        pays_fee: Pays::No,
    })
}
```

Extrinsic basically calls `prevalidate_something` function to perform all operations that may potentially fail (it emits events and modifies storage as well and during execution it may fail). If `prevalidate_something` succedes, then `do_something` is called, which performs operations that do not fail and in the end weight is calculated based on `prevalidate_data`.

As long as it is unsigned transaction, it is validated in `ValidateUnsigned::validate_unsigned` trait. According to documentation, this function can be called multiple times, the same thing applies to `ValidateUnsigned::pre_dispatch`. But if `validate_unsigned` will be called just before right dispatch (with TransactionSource::InBlock as argument), all operations performed by `prevalidate_something` will be persisted, even if it will fail:

```rust
    /// Validate the call right before dispatch.
    ///
    /// This method should be used to prevent transactions already in the pool
    /// (i.e. passing [`validate_unsigned`](Self::validate_unsigned)) from being included in blocks
    /// in case they became invalid since being added to the pool.
    ///
    /// By default it's a good idea to call [`validate_unsigned`](Self::validate_unsigned) from
    /// within this function again to make sure we never include an invalid transaction. Otherwise
    /// the implementation of the call or this method will need to provide proper validation to
    /// ensure that the transaction is valid.
    ///
    /// Changes made to storage *WILL* be persisted if the call returns `Ok`.
    fn pre_dispatch(call: &Self::Call) -> Result<(), TransactionValidityError> {
        Self::validate_unsigned(TransactionSource::InBlock, call)
            .map(|_| ())
            .map_err(Into::into)
    }
```

In theory, we can protect it by moving call of `prevalidate_something` to `validate_unsigned` and wrap it in additional transactional layer, so all operations will be reverted once it will fail:

```rust
let prevalidate_data = frame_support::storage::with_storage_layer(|| {
    Pallet::<T>::prevalidate_something(
        ..
    )
}).map_err(|err| InvalidTransaction::Custom(err.into()))?;

// We can use prevalidate_data to define priority as well

ValidTransaction::with_tag_prefix("Prefix")
    .priority(42)
    .propagate(!matches!(source, TransactionSource::InBlock))
    .build();
```

But how to get `prevalidate_data` for weight calculation, in case that it will be not called inside extrinsic, but in `validate_unsigned`?

In theory, we can call `prevalidate_something` in `validate_unsigned` wrapped in [with_transaction](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/storage/fn.with_transaction.html) and always return `TransactionOutcome::Rollback` and call `prevalidate_something` in extrinsic as usuall, but it causes that this computations are performed twice for `InBlock` case.

Maybe adding StorageValue like below will solve the issue, so in `validate_unsigned` weight will be calculated based on `prevalidate_data` and later read in the dispatch of extrinsic?

```rust
// Last weight of the transaction
#[pallet::storage]
pub type LastWeight<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, Weight, ValueQuery>;
```

```rust
let prevalidate_data = frame_support::storage::with_storage_layer(|| {
    Pallet::<T>::prevalidate_something(
        ..
    )
}).map_err(|err| InvalidTransaction::Custom(err.into()))?;

let weight = Pallet::<T>::calc_weight(&prevalidate_data);

LastWeight::<T>::mutate(|last_weight| {
    *last_weight = weight;
});

// We can use prevalidate_data to define priority as well

ValidTransaction::with_tag_prefix("Prefix")
    .priority(42)
    .propagate(!matches!(source, TransactionSource::InBlock))
    .build();
```

- Is there some possible race condition within this approach?
- Can we assume, that right after `InBlock` dispatch, no other extrinsic will be set between?
- Do you have some suggestions, how to handle an extrinsic, which has a prevalidate function that emits events and modifies storage?

Answer (score 0):

> if transaction fails, it seems like it leaves garbage in runtime, due events/storage modifications are not reverted.

This is incorrect. Like any extrinsic the default is that state changes will only persist if it doesn't return an error.

The `SignedExtension`'s validation don't include the full logic of an extrinsic (see first answer [extrinsic validation lifecycle](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5647/difference-between-signedextension-default-behavior-vs-actual-behavior-expand/5939#5939)). More specifically, for your 'unsigned' case, only the `check_weight` has a `validate_unsigned` implementation and the rest return the default (`Ok`).

`SignedExtensions` are called from the transaction pool to initially validate a transaction and when applying the transactions from a block (`pre_dispatch` is called which default implementation is that it calls `validate`/`validate_unsigned`). The weight for `SignedExtensions` is handled through [ExtrinsicBaseWeight](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/signed-extensions-and-weights).

So to your example, `prevalidate_something` will only be executed when the extrinsic is applied from a block.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure about that? I have added debug logs to print source of the transaction each time a validation is triggered and I see that it is always called twice, first time with `TransactionSource::Local/External` and second time with `InBlock`:


`2023-08-31 09:30:21.032  WARN      offchain-worker pallet_template::pallet: Received Local transaction
2023-08-31 09:30:24.001  WARN tokio-runtime-worker pallet_template::pallet: Recieved InBlock transaction `

Comment: Validation of the extrinsic's logic or SignedExtension logic?

Comment: That it will be executed only when extrinsic is applied from a block

Comment: Can you make an edit to your question and be specific about your question, it is hard to follow you.

Comment: Sure, I have added TLDR section

Comment: Made an edit, let me know if it is still unclear